# How to remove the HOME menu item

Tags: menus, wp-list-pages

I am using wordpress 3.4.1.
I am mainly creating a static site and for that have created and arrnaged the pages, and wordpress has nicely created the pages in proper nav-menu format for me, which is good.
But, it has also added a link to 'Home' in the nav-menu. How can i remove that?

NOTE: I prefer any other answer than using the menu section and  creating a new menu and assigning it as primary menu.

Comment: yep! this works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a good solution posted over at .org

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-home-from-menu-1#post-2215239

> You can remove the "Home" link using a filter. Add this to your Theme's functions.php file:
>
> ```
>    function mytheme_nav_menu_args( $args ) {
>        $args['show_home'] = false;
>        return $args;
>    }
> ```

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'mytheme_nav_menu_args' );

> And if you want to remove the "Home" link from the default fallback menu, add another filter:
>
> ```
>    add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'mytheme_nav_menu_args' );
> ```

Comment: Okay, but happens when that solution doesn't work either?

Comment: @Shawn This is an accepted solution. Are you implementing it properly?

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: @MikeKormendy Most likely because We're at 4.8+ now.

Comment: Yep, just letting others know.